# Using a php session to get information with WHERE in Mysqli

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I was trying to use a session set by my login system to fetch information in the database about a user who didn't fill in in a form.

The code I'm using right now:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_ID = '$uid'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 $row['Unique_ID'];
 $row['AC'];
?>

<b><?php echo $row['AC']; ?></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<?php
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
Welcome to the armour coins shop! Here you can spend your hard earned coins on some shiny armour and weapons. You gain coins by leveling up in-game. You can do this by preforming laberous activities. <a href="?explain=leveling">Click here for more information about leveling</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>                           
<form action="buy.php" method="POST" class="form-inline" style="display:inline-block;">
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php echo $_POST['uid']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="127">
<input type="submit" value="Buy Brynie">

<?php
}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
     $uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uid']);

     $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."' AND Unique_ID = '".$uid."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['Uid'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
        ?>
```

As you can see, I'm using a session, but I want to get information in the database according the user.

This doesn't work:

```
$uid = ($_SESSION['Uid']) ?>

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_ID = '$uid'");
```

Comment: Please verify that $uid actually has a value in it.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you ever call `session_start()`. Without that, `$_SESSION` is just a plain variable like any other whose contents will be killed when the script exits.

Comment: Forgot to add base.php which houses a session start

Comment: I would recommend upgrading your entire code to mysqli, as im seeing a mixture of the depreciated library and the improved extension.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a session_start() in your code you need to add session_start() before you can use sessions
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php